# Windows Phone 8.1 : ToggleSwitch isn't working as expected

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Application which is being developed from past one year.

Here's how ToggleSwitch is used in the code

```
<ToggleSwitch IsOn="{Binding IsSplit, Mode=TwoWay}"
              IsEnabled="True"
              Foreground="{StaticResource PrimaryColor3Brush}"
              OffContent="Off"
              OnContent="On"/>
```

ToggleSwitch is used in a few pages. The behavior of the ToggleSwitch is buggy. The ToggleSwitch does not detect either the "drag" event or "click" event when it is done on the vertical slider of the Switch. The following image shows the arrow pointed to the part of the switch where click or drag doesn't get defected.

[image: Toggle Switch Slider doesn't detect click or drag]

This is a problem on every ToggleSwitch in this application.
However when I create a fresh Windows Phone 8.1 project and add a ToggleSwitch, it works smooth as expected. So this way I was able to isolate that the problem is happening only on our current project.

So to debug this, I tried the following

1. I saw if we had any default styles being applied to ToggleSwitches in our app in general that modified the original behavior - No There was None

   2. I created a fresh new page in my current app where I created only a ToggleSwitch within a Grid - No luck, the ToggleSwitch was still buggy.
   3. I used Blend to edit a copy of the default template of the ToggleSwitch, pasted the same onto the ToggleSwitch on my page - Still, the behavior didn't get fixed.
   4. I tried to see if any of the ancestor classes of ToggleSwitch had been applied a default different Style - No, there was none.

I've spent hours on this but I'm not sure what could be causing the ToggleSwitch to act buggy. I would highly appreciate if anyone has any idea of what could be happening or if they could share a few other things that I could try so that it might fix.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean (2nd point) that you have a fresh *Page* only with *ToggleSwitch* and the TS also doesn't work? Is the page inheritating from something, any extensions/modifications? Has TS any binding/style/other defined or it's just standard one?

Comment: Yes, in the 2nd point I mean - even on the fresh page, toggle switch is buggy.
The Toggle Switch has a binding as to when to be switched off or on. But that's working as expected with respect to functionality. The UI is still buggy. 
I did a find all in my project with TargetType="ToggleSwitch", and none of them were default, they all had names and that was not used as part of Style Static Resource for this ToggleSwitch.

Comment: `The ToggleSwitch does not detect either the "drag" event or "click" event when it is done on the vertical slider of the Switch.` Since you have no style applied on ToggleSwitch, the culprit is likely a style applied on whatever control the ToggleSwitch is using to display the vertical slider (likely a `Rectangle` or a `Border`). If you have any style applying globally to those elements, check whether you're doing anything funky inside

Comment: @KooKiz - Thanks a lot for this suggestion. I received help to figure out this bug. 
Apparently, I had a width applied to a "Thumb" which was making the toggle switch only take events in that small width which caused this issue. I changed the width, now it's working properly.